# [VBA][Excel] Find all occurrences and Sum values of nearby cell

Tags: vba, excel

So I have this problem:

I have sheet named Database and in there are records that I need to find in my main sheet (sheet1), then take near (to the left) cell number and sum them up all Then drop it in Database sheet right after item that I search for. (reference in screenshot) This is how my database sheet looks like:

[image: Database sheet]

This needs to loop for every record in Database sheet down.

I tried to loop thru range, but I got stuck deciding how to find values without knowing range, because it's might be anywhere. You can see structure in screenshot

This is how main Sheet looks like:

[image]

So short description of algorithm:

**It takes number from Database sheet, find all occurrences of that in Main sheet and sums all numbers together of that occurrence, then simply places it in cell next to record that we searched for in the first place**

Any suggestion guys?

please forgive for my english it's not my native language. :)

Comment: How do you identify the range when you look at it?  You can do the same thing in your formula or macro.

Comment: Tell me more. I looked up formulas as SUMIF and SUMIFS but as for now those can't achieve what I need

Comment: **How do you identify the range when you look at it?**

Comment: By simply looking at top  and left rulers (I don't know how to call them) there I can see A1 or G5 and so on

Comment: That is not helpful. What is it about the "rulers" (and I don't know what you mean by that), that let's you know that you are looking at the desired range?

Comment: Do you look at the entire worksheet?  And just look for matching content?  Or do you limit your "look" to just certain columns or rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear to me how you identify the values you are looking for.  If they might be anywhere on the `MAIN` sheet, then you can use a simple `SUMIF`.

Assume your Range where the values "might" be would be no larger than, for example, A1:Z1000.  You would just search the whole range, and return matching data in the adjacent column. So, if your `search_term` is in `A1`:

```
B1: =SUMIF(MAIN!$A$1:$Z$1000,A1,MAIN!$B$1:$ZZ$1000)
```

If there might be confusing entries in some of the columns, you'll need to be more specific as to how you determine which columns to search.

**EDIT**  After seeing your latest screenshots, I suggest one of the following formulas.

If the column header makes no difference, and

- your Database sheet has the Detale code starting in A1 and extending down the column
- In the formulas below change the 1000 to encompass all the rows that you might possibly use, even if some are blank now.
- Note that `sum_range` is the same size as, but offset by one column from the `criteria ranges`

  ```
  B1: =SUMIF(Presu_planas!$A$40:$Z$1000,A1,Presu_planas!$B$40:$AA$1000)
  ```

If you must restrict looking for those codes only in the columns that have Detale in Row 40, then try the following:

This formula must be **array-entered**:

```
B1: =SUM((Presu_planas!$A$40:$Z$40="Detale")*(Presu_planas!$A$40:$Z$1000=A1)*IFERROR(--Presu_planas!$B$40:$AA$1000,0))
```

---

To **array-enter** a formula, after entering
the formula into the cell or formula bar, hold down
<kbd>ctrl + shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>.  If you did this
correctly, Excel will place braces <kbd>**{...}**</kbd> around the formula.

Comment: No, value that I need to search for is in Database sheet and Records that needs to be searched and summed up is in Main sheet... And those records can be in whole document like in this picture

http://prntscr.com/e0lusy

Comment: @CunamiRokas if you put the formula I suggested on your database sheet, it will search on the mainsheet. Just adjust the cell and sheet references to what you need.

Comment: Just ensure that your range is all-inclusive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following FindAll function to find the relevant values in the Main worksheet.

From there use a Range.Offset(0, 1).Value to access the values and sum them

```
Function FindAll(What, _
    Optional SearchWhat As Variant, _
    Optional LookIn, _
    Optional LookAt, _
    Optional SearchOrder, _
    Optional SearchDirection As XlSearchDirection = xlNext, _
    Optional MatchCase As Boolean = False, _
    Optional MatchByte, _
    Optional SearchFormat) As Range

    'LookIn can be xlValues or xlFormulas, _
     LookAt can be xlWhole or xlPart, _
     SearchOrder can be xlByRows or xlByColumns, _
     SearchDirection can be xlNext, xlPrevious, _
     MatchCase, MatchByte, and SearchFormat can be True or False. _
     Before using SearchFormat = True, specify the appropriate settings for the Application.FindFormat _
     object; e.g. Application.FindFormat.NumberFormat = "General;-General;""-"""

    Dim SrcRange As Range
    If IsMissing(SearchWhat) Then
        Set SrcRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    ElseIf TypeOf SearchWhat Is Range Then
        Set SrcRange = IIf(SearchWhat.Cells.Count = 1, SearchWhat.Parent.UsedRange, SearchWhat)
    ElseIf TypeOf SearchWhat Is Worksheet Then
        Set SrcRange = SearchWhat.UsedRange
    Else: SrcRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    End If
    If SrcRange Is Nothing Then Exit Function

    'get the first matching cell in the range first
    With SrcRange.Areas(SrcRange.Areas.Count)
        Dim FirstCell As Range: Set FirstCell = .Cells(.Cells.Count)
    End With

    Dim CurrRange As Range: Set CurrRange = SrcRange.Find(What:=What, After:=FirstCell, LookIn:=LookIn, LookAt:=LookAt, _
        SearchDirection:=SearchDirection, MatchCase:=MatchCase, MatchByte:=MatchByte, SearchFormat:=SearchFormat)

    If Not CurrRange Is Nothing Then
        Set FindAll = CurrRange
        Do
            Set CurrRange = SrcRange.Find(What:=What, After:=CurrRange, LookIn:=LookIn, LookAt:=LookAt, _
            SearchDirection:=SearchDirection, MatchCase:=MatchCase, MatchByte:=MatchByte, SearchFormat:=SearchFormat)
            If CurrRange Is Nothing Then Exit Do
            If Application.Intersect(FindAll, CurrRange) Is Nothing Then
                Set FindAll = Application.Union(FindAll, CurrRange)
            Else: Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
    End If
End Function
```